# Last() Identifier not found in C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

My code is as below (this is for doubly linked list structure, adding a new node):

```
    void addhead(student* node_, student*& olist)
    {
        if(!olist)
        {
            olist=node_;
        }   
        else
        {
            node_->flink=olist;
            node_->blink=last(olist);  //ERROR
            olist->blink=node_;
            last(olist)->flink=node_;  //ERROR
            olist=node_;
        }
    }
```

and I get *"identifier not found"* error for the `last()` function.

My student struct and the array initialization is as below:

```
public struct student
        {
        public:
        char ogrNo[13];
        char isim[100];
        char tck[11];
        char dYeri[50];
        char dTarihi[50];
        char bolum[255];
        char sinif[100];
        char mail[50];
        char cep[50];
        char adres[255];


        ogrenci* blink;
        ogrenci* flink;
        };

student* o=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
```

Is there a way to implement a `last()` function or equivalent in C++/CLI (Studio.NET 2010)? This code is clean for unmanaged C++.

Comment: The compiler has the same problem I do, I don't see a last() function either.  This code doesn't have anything to do with C++/CLI, it is C code.

Comment: @HansPassant didn't you see the "public struct"?

Comment: Are you using C++? `malloc` and excessive pointer magic are not things I would expect. Why not use classes and references? EDIT: Templates might also be good.

Comment: @user1610015 : I guess what Hans means is that the issue is not specific to C++/CLI, and applies equally to C/C++. :)

Comment: Tanks to everyone, @Waleed Khan: It was a homework of my cousin to do with structs, indeed, the used code was specifically written for C (mentioned in his lecture notes) and in the homework, was asked to implement in C++. I'm also new in C++, an unfortunately had started this project in VS 2010. This will be the last to use CLI for me :) Could you also recommend me the best Visual C++ editor?

Comment: This is *not* C++/CLI.  From what I can tell, it's simply pure C (not even C++).  That being said, if `last()` doesn't work, then show us the code for `last`, please. What is the exact ERROR that you're seeing when you compile?

Answer (score 0):

You can add **first** and **last** members which you manage so that they always point to the first and last nodes of the list.

But you don't need to implement linked list functionality for every class, there are already linked list classes in C++/CLI:

- System::Collections::Generic::LinkedList
- cliext::list
- std::list

Comment: Let me spend some time for this advice, thanks, I'll be back.

Comment: I tried to implement the linkedlist class as mentioned in MSDN: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2), but there, a LinkedList of String^ is used as below: `array<String^>^ words =
            { "the", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "dog" };
        LinkedList<String^>^ sentence = gcnew LinkedList<String^>(words); ` The problem is, how can I define an array of Students (struct or class) as a LinkedList?

Comment: I'm not sure wether your Student class is a managed class (**ref class** or **value class**) or an unmanaged class (just **class**). If it's managed, use LinkedList<Student^>. If it's unmanaged, use std::list<Student> (without the **^**).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself... Thanks to all contributions, also future comments will be useful.

I tried the System::Collections::Generic::LinkedList class, but I found it's impossible to define a LinkedList of Struct or Class Array (whether as ref or not).

Then, to bypass the last() function that is not supported in C++/CLI, I defined an

```
int last=-1;
```

to handle the last element of the struct array. Then modified the above code as follows:

```
void addhead(ogrenci* node_, ogrenci*& olist)
    {
        if(!olist)
        {
            olist=node_;
            last++;
        }   
        else
        {
            node_->flink=olist;
            node_->blink=&olist[last];  //Orig: node_->blink=last(olist);
            olist->blink=node_;
            olist[last].flink=node_;    //Orig: last(olist)->flink=node_;
            olist=node_;
            last++;
        }
    }
```

This solved my problem, but open to your comments...

Comment: This code seemed to work, at least didn't give error, but when using it, I recognized that flink and blink does not work properly. I put 3 seperate records into a struct array, but when writing them on the form, there seems to be oly 1 record in the linked list. This shows that my list is NOT linked to each other :) I will keep studying on this :)

Answer (score 0):

What does this line mean?  I mean, why these two character together *& ?

```
       void addhead(student* node_, student*& olist)
```

Comment: That's a reference to a pointer to `student`.  Hmmm.. I guess that's the only thing that makes it C++, to be honest ;)